# can't install android SDK on visual studio on mac

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, sdk, installation

I tried to install android SDK by SDK manager on visual studio on mac

The installing package is downloaded well, but it is failed to install file to the local disk.

My mac version is 10.12.5

Visual Studio version is 7.0.1 for mac community

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmDjj.png]

Comment: So, what is the error?

Comment: Please take an image, or paste the complete error message.

Comment: you can manually download the Android SDK Platform 24 ( http://downloads.puresoftware.org/files/android/SDK/)  and you can place the respective zip file in the corresponding folder. ( Tools - > SDK Manager -> Locations ).